# How to create a list of options for slash commands in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a slash command in the `discord.js` bot with one of the options receiving the `type` as an array of options, likely the following:

```
export enum LabTypes {
  Simulated = "SIMULATED",
  Odyssey = "ODYSSEY",
  Guided = "GUIDED",
  CloudCity = "CLOUD_CITY",
  CommandCenter = "COMMAND_CENTER",
  Embeded = "EMBEDED"
}
```

And

```
  {
    name: "type",
    description: "Enter the HOL type",
    type: this.commandsType.LAB_TYPES,
    required: true,
  }
```

I would like in the `type` parameter, the `LabTypes` options to be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by including the `choices` on my question.
Here's the code:

```
      {
        name: "type",
        description: "Enter the HOL type",
        type: this.commandsType.STRING,
        required: true,
        choices: [
          {
            name: "GUIDED",
            value: "GUIDED"
          },
          {
            name: "ODYSSEY",
            value: "ODYSSEY"
          },
          {
            name: "SIMULATED",
            value: "SIMULATED"
          },
          {
            name: "CLOUD CITY",
            value: "CLOUD_CITY"
          },
          {
            name: "COMMAND CENTER",
            value: "COMMAND_CENTER"
          },
          {
            name: "EMBEDED",
            value: "EMBEDED"
          },
        ]
      }
```

Simple as that.

References: https://canary.discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands